# LWC: Edit file details in modal

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-modal

I want to edit file details and update it. i dont know where i am going wrong, i have used lightning datatable for display of all file and on click of edit file button modal open up which shows editable fields of that particular file.

[image]

html code

```html
<template if:true={isShowEditFile}>
   <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
      <div class="slds-modal__container">
         <!-- modal header start -->
         <header class="slds-modal__header">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={hideModalBox}>
               <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                               alternative-text="close"
                               variant="inverse"
                               size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
            </button>
            <h2 id="modal-heading-02" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Edit File Details</h2>
         </header>
         <!-- modal body start -->
         <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-2">         
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
               <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_3-of-12 slds-medium-size_1-of-12 slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
                  <span>
                     <label class="bold_label">
                        <template
                           if:true={requiredValue}>
                              <span>*</span>
                        </template>
                        Title                         
                     </label>
                  </span>
               </div>
               <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_9-of-12 slds-medium-size_1-of-12 slds-size_1-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
                  <span>
                     <lightning-input class="" name="fileTitle" required={requiredValue} label="Title" variant="label-hidden" value={fileTitle} onchange={handleFormInputChange}></lightning-input>
                  </span>
               </div>
               <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_3-of-12 slds-medium-size_1-of-12 slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
                  <span>
                     <label class="bold_label">
                        Description                         
                     </label>
                  </span>
               </div>
               <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_9-of-12 slds-medium-size_1-of-12 slds-size_1-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
                  <span>
                     <lightning-textarea name="description" label="Description" variant="label-hidden" value={description} onchange={handleFormInputChange}></lightning-textarea>
                  </span>
               </div>
               <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_3-of-12 slds-medium-size_1-of-12 slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
                  <span>
                     <label class="bold_label">
                        Created                         
                     </label>
                  </span>
               </div>
               <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_9-of-12 slds-medium-size_1-of-12 slds-size_1-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
                  <span>
                     <label class="bold_label">
                        Created Date                     
                     </label>
                  </span>
               </div>
               <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_3-of-12 slds-medium-size_1-of-12 slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
                  <span>
                     <label class="bold_label">
                        Last Modified Date                        
                     </label>
                  </span>
               </div>
               <div class="slds-col slds-large-size_9-of-12 slds-medium-size_1-of-12 slds-size_1-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--medium slds-m-bottom_medium">
                  <span>
                     <label class="bold_label">
                        Last Modified Date Value                        
                     </label>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
         </div>
         <!-- modal footer start-->
         <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
            <lightning-button label="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick={hideModalBox}></lightning-button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" title="Save" onclick={handleSaveClick}></lightning-button>
         </footer>
      </div>
   </section>
   <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
</template>
<!--edit file details end-->
</template>
<!-- modal end -->
```

js code main issue is here.. value is displayed in `this.fileTitle` & `this.description`, but when i am trying to pass this same value inside `handleSaveClick` it is coming as undefined

```javascript
editFile(currentRow){
    this.rowName = currentRow.label;
    console.log('seletedRow:' , this.rowName)
}

handleFormInputChange(event){
    if (event.target.name == 'fileTitle') {
        this.fileTitle = event.target.value
    } else if (event.target.name == 'description') {
        this.description = event.target.value
    }     
}

handleSaveClick(){
    const Ftitle = this.fileTitle
    console.log('title:' , this.Ftitle)
    const fileDescription = this.description
    console.log('fileDescription:' , this.fileDescription)
    let fileName = this.rowName
    console.log('actualFileName:' , this.fileName)

    fileEditClass({Ftitle, fileDescription, fileName})
    .then(result=>{
        const title = `$File "{title}" was saved.`
        this.toast(title)
    })
}
```

apex code.. all three value here are null.

```apex
@AuraEnabled
    public static String editFileDetails(String fileTitle, String fileDescription, String actualFileName){
        try{
            System.debug('inside edit file apex class');
            System.debug('fileTitle : ' + fileTitle);
            System.debug('fileDescription : ' + fileDescription);
            System.debug('actualFileName : ' + actualFileName);
            List<ContentDocument> fileList = [SELECT Id, Description, Title FROM ContentDocument WHERE Title LIKE :actualFileName];
            System.debug('fileList' + fileList[0]);
            for(ContentDocument cd: fileList){
                cd.Description = fileDescription;
                cd.Title = fileTitle;
            }
            update fileList;
            System.debug('update successfull' + fileList[0]);
            return 'SUCCESS';
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: We are missing some essential parts of the JS file, e.g. the declaration of fileEditClass. Please include them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here:

```js
    //it should be an json object and the name should match the apex parameters
...
    fileEditClass({fileTitle:Ftitle, fileDescription:fileDescription, actualFileName:fileName}) ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your instant help..!!

Comment: @DhirenRaut if this solved your problem could you mark it as the correct answer?
In this way avoid people to stuck in the same problem.
Regards